# Kotlin default parameter only work at the end

Tags: kotlin, named-parameters, default-parameters

I want some of my function parameter to be optional, so I used default parameter as follow :

```
fun defaultparameter(param1: String = "", param2: String = "", param3: Int = 0)
```

this work I can do this :

```
defaultparameter()
defaultparameter("titi")
defaultparameter("titi", "tata")
```

I can do this because default parameter are at the end but when my parameter is in the middle: `defaultparameter("titi", 0)`
This doesn't work and it is asking me for `param2`.

I am guessing that the compiler can only omit parameter if there are at the end but is that normal? I understand that when parameter are the same type the compiler couldn't know which on is which but here I have a type `Int` at then end so I thought it would work.

My question is: default parameter only works at the end? or am I missing something? And is there any way to achieve this without using polymorphism and declaring other function with only 2 parameter: one `String` and one `Int`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the *Kotlin* [Named Arguments](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#named-arguments) documentation:

> When you use named arguments in a function call, you can freely change the order they are listed in, and if you want to use their default values you can just leave them out altogether.

I.e. call the method as follows

```
defaultparameter(param1 = "titi", param3 = 0)
```

Comment: Thank i was missing the notion about named arguments

Answer (score 6):

You can use keyword arguments:

```kotlin
defaultparameter("titi", param3 = 2)
```